# CSV file upload in Php using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using Php as a frontend and Java as a backend. I have created an Post API for uploading file and using curl for api request.

I have hit my Api using Postman at that time it works fine but i am facing prodblem when i request api using Curl i don't eble to get what i am doing wrong.

Here is the curl requested data :-

```
 $data2 = array(
              'file' =>
                  '@'            . $data1->file->tmp_name
                  . ';filename=' . $data1->file->name
                  . ';type='     . $data1->file->type
            );
```

This is how i am sending curl request:-

```
$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$this->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //parveen
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); //parveen
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data2); 

        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type:'.$this->service->contentType, 
            'Launcher:'.$this->serverName,
            'domain:'.$this->service->domain,  
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        $this->responseBody=curl_exec($ch);
```

Links where i find this solution:-

[enter link description here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/sending-files-using-curl/#example)

I search a lot to find the solution but nothing is worked for me so please help me .
Thanks

Comment: please elaborate more on your question, e.g. showing us the error message, and showing us more code

Comment: @samAlvin i have updated the question. I am not getting any error from server but data is not received in the API (backend java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you're trying to upload the file hasn't been supported since the PHP5 days, and even in 5.5+ you'd need `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD` to upload with @. use CURLFile when uploading files, like

```
 $data2 = array(
              'file' => new CURLFile($data1->file->name,$data1->file->type,$data1->file->tmp_name)
    );
```

also, don't use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST for POST requests, just use CURLOPT_POST. (this is also true for GET requests and CURLOPT_HTTPGET )

also, check the return value of curl_setopt, if there was a problem setting your option, it returns bool(false), in which case you should use curl_error() to extract the error message. use something like

```
function ecurl_setopt($ch,int $option,$value){
    if(!curl_setopt($ch,$option,$value)){
        throw new \RuntimeException('curl_setopt failed! '.curl_error($ch));
    }
}
```

and protip, whenever you're debugging curl code, use CURLOPT_VERBOSE, it prints lots of useful debugging info

Comment: Thank for reply. I try the same way but still it is not working. But now i succeed to find error using curl_error($ch).So now i am geting an error "couldn't open file "xyz.csv"".I find a lot but nothing help me.

Comment: @ParveenGuleria there's your problem! either the filepath you provide is wrong, OR the user account that php is running under, doesn't have permissions to access the file. what does this output? `system('namei -l '.escapeshellarg($data1->file->tmp_name));`

Comment: It's working now. The file path i provide is wrong.There i have to give absolute path than it's working fine.Thank you so much for help.